# Selectively drawing to some outputs in shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, framebuffer

I have a framebuffer object with 2 outputs:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
layout(location = 1) out uint object_id;
```

In my shader I also receive a boolean value, which tells me if I should write to the second output or not.

```
color = some_color;
if (condition) {
    object_id = value;
}
```

Is this possible to achieve?

I thought I could do it with glBlendEquation(1, GL_MAX) and just write 0 in the else part of the if, but that doesn't seem to work with r32ui textures.

Comment: Ok so in your vertex shader you have those two outs, and you don't want to write to the second one. Can I ask why? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Is it possible for you to just ignore the object id in the fragment shader instead if it fails some condition?

Comment: "I have a framebuffer object", these are my outputs in the fragment shader. And ignoring outputs in fragment shader doesn't work, since they then become undefined.

Comment: What is condition? A uniform? Something the shader calculates?

Comment: It comes as vertex shader input.

Answer (score 2):

> In my shader I also receive a boolean value, which tells me if I should write to the second output or not.
>
> *What is condition? A uniform? Something the shader calculates?*
>
> It comes as vertex shader input.

If you don't write to one of the user-defined fragment shader output variables, then this is an undefined behavior and the result which is stored to the framebuffer is undefined.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 17.4. WHOLE FRAMEBUFFER OPERATIONS; page 516](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> If a fragment shader writes to no user-defined output variables, the values of the fragment colors following shader execution are undefined, and may differ for each fragment color. **If some, but not all user-defined output variables are written, the values of fragment colors corresponding to unwritten variables are similarly undefined.**

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 15.2. SHADER EXECUTION; page 492](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> When a fragment shader terminates, the value of each active user-defined output variable is written to components of the fragment color output to which it is bound.

---

> I thought I could do it with `glBlendEquation(1, GL_MAX)` and just write 0 in the else part of the if, but that doesn't seem to work with r32ui textures.

That is not possible, because blending is not applied to integer format buffers.

[OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 17.3.6 Blending; page 502](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> Blending applies only if the color buffer has a fixed-point or floating-point
>   format. If the color buffer has an integer format, proceed to the next operation.

---

What you can do is to use a fixed point format for the framebuffer data store, like `GL_R16`. `GL_R16` has 16 bits to store the values from 0.0 to 1.0 and blending is provided. Further `GL_R16` is provided for both, textures and renderbuffers. The corresponding data type is `float`.
You can store a unsigned integer to it by "normalizing" the value by dividing it by 2^16-1:

```
layout(location = 1) out vec4 object_id;

object_id.r = float(value) / (exp2(16.0)-1.0);
```